# Change the +200 amount on the home page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, stackexchange.com

[image]

I request to make this +15. +200 is misleading, since it's part of a bounty, which is not a basic feature.

Comment: It's not part of a bounty necessarily. It could be an accumulation of a day's worth of reputation. To that end, +15 is equally arbitrary.

Comment: @Werner: It's displayed using the bounty styling. That said, I think it's entirely reasonable to display a bounty award + checkmark to represent some of the highest discrete, concisely-representable marks of achievement to strive for. ("Nice high score" is hard to make discrete.)

Comment: You do realize the bounty indicator appears directly below the accept mark on the left side? And that value would *never* be +15 since it's not possible to receive that amount from a bounty (the lowest you could possibly receive is +25)?

Comment: Fine, never mind then. +15 was supposed to be 1 accepted answer. hence the checkmark. But whatever. and @animuson I do know the bounty indicator appears there, so then lets change the whole layout of this image, which ofc no one will accept.

Comment: @interwebz Well, your objection there was that it looked like a bounty amount. It's *supposed to be* a bounty amount. The icon to the left has the voting arrows, and this one has the accept mark and bounty indicator. But in the end, I think we're putting way too much thought into this. They're just supposed to be aesthetically pleasing icons so the page doesn't look so dull and boring. No one likes looking at a page of plain text.

Comment: @animuson thats fine.

Answer (score 5):

Hit the rep cap on any site and then click this button in the top bar:

[image]

This is why we have the [mortarboard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard), [epic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/145/epic) and [legendary badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary) :) Because you'll see:

`+200`

... in your achievements for the last 24 hours. It's not just a bounty thing, and while it's not *common*, it's not exactly rare to happen. It's the most rep you can earn on a site in any day, and I don't think it's disingenuous to have that in an illustration.

If you've got a suggestion on how we could depict that as more of a goal, I'm happy to talk about it, but I don't see a compelling reason to *not* use the depiction.

Comment: It looks so... dark, without the context of the top bar.

Comment: At first, new users have no idea that this 200 limit is a thing. I suggested starting with something more basic, such as an accepted answer +15.